# Is 'promptus' a valid word?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, is-it-a-word

I did a Google:define on `Promptus` and think it has Latin origin. But since I don't see it in the English dictionaries,  I am not sure if I can use it at all in my conversation.

Comment: Why do you think it is an English word in the first place? Please give some context.

Comment: There's certainly a Latin word, *promptus*. It's where we get *prompt* in English.

Comment: Looks like NARQ to me, regardless of where OP found the "word", and with what sense he wants to use it.

Comment: I've provided an answer, though I'm still at a loss as to why anyone would desire to use a word in conversation that they did not yet know. Surely the desire would come after the knowledge.

Comment: often, they mistakenly speak of the promptus of love. sad, really.

Comment: @TimLymington Idk, I just got it in my head somehow! Just wanted to know if its actually a word or not.

and whats narq?

Comment: Not A Real Question; the reason why this was in fact closed. I am afraid this tends to happen if you do no research (or at least do not show any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Latin word *promptus*, from which we get *prompt*.

[Burton's Legal Thesaurus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071472622) glosses it as "expeditious, prompt, ready (prepared)".

So, while it's Latin, it has been used in English, in legal contexts at least.